# Why does the RM-Client not create Backlog items for failed deploys

Tags: tfs, msbuild, release-management, continuous-deployment, ms-release-management

I Manage a release using Microsoft Release Management for Visual Studio Update 3,
i expected the release management server to create a work-item/bug backlog item if a release gets rejected, but this is not the case. Is this not possible in the current Version (2013 Update 3)?

If not are there any plans to add this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

This is not available out of the box. It is something that is in the backlog and so should be available in a future version.

In the meantime, here is a workaround.

Add a `Rollback Always` activity in your deployment. In that activity, add a component that calls a PS script or executable that would create a bug work item. A component is needed here to be able to access the different metadata of a deployment.

The different metadata available are:

- BuildDefinition
- BuildNumber
- PackageLocation
- ServerName
- ServerDnsName
- TeamProject
- TfsCollection

For example, have a `__MySource__` token in your script or command and set its value to one of the metadata variable like this:

[image]

Comment: This does work if the deployment fails and the target is online although a rejected release/deployment does not trigger a rollback therefore this sadly cannot be tracked as bugreport.